# How to draw wireframe sphere in opengl es

Tags: geometry, wireframe

Can you please submit a code for drawing a basic wireframe sphere without texturing it. I found plenty of examples but they use 3 kind of buffers like normal,texture and vertices. Is there any simple comprehensive way to draw a sphere using GL_TRIANGLE_FAN or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and using only vertex and fragment shader.

Thank you!

Comment: _"Can you please submit a code for drawing a basic wireframe sphere without texturing it."_ That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DrawSphere(GLdouble radius, int longitudeSubdiv, int latitudeSubdiv)
{
// issue corresponding GL command
    //glPolygonMode(GL_BACK,GL_FILL);

    //gluSphere(m_quadrObj,radius,longitudeSubdiv,latitudeSubdiv);
    float color1[3] = {1.0,0.0,0.0};
    float shininess = 64.0f;
    float specularColor[] = {1.0, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shininess); // range 0 ~ 128
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specularColor);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1,1,1);// *
    glColor3fv(color1);

    gluSphere(m_quadrObj,radius,longitudeSubdiv,latitudeSubdiv);

    glPopMatrix();
    //glColor3fv(color2);

}
```